# C# Linq to SQL - INSERT if data is not existed based on Time(AM or PM)

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I currently finishing my payroll system which is a school project. I've been stucked with the employee's DTR or Daily Time Record.

The time format I've been using is 12-hour format. the in_am,out_am ... column data types are varchar

For Example If time is '09:12 AM' and I used a count procedure below:

```
 create procedure check_in_am
            @date datetime,
            @id int
            as
            declare @r int
            select @r = count(*) from tbl_timelog
            where date_log=@date and id = @id 
            return @r
```

then compare the return int with = 0 on my DTR

```
int checkAM = cls.Check_In_AM(DateTime.Parse(date.ToString()), int.Parse(txtID.Text));
if (checkAM==0)
'INSERT HERE'//time-in
else
'UPDATE HERE' //time-out
```

the problem with this code is I can only manipulate two columns which is the in_am and out_am but how could I manipulate the in_pm and out_pm.

Here's what I've been thinking.

```
if (DateTime.Now.ToString("tt") == "AM")
                    {
                int checkAM = cls.Check_In_AM(DateTime.Parse(date.ToString()), int.Parse(txtID.Text));
if (checkAM==0)
'INSERT HERE'//time-in
else
'UPDATE HERE' //this part where there is data for time-in and the null value of time-out will be updated based on the time it is been executed.
                    }
else
{
if(checkAM == 1)
{
'UPDATE HERE' // this will update the in_pm column with its latest value.
}
}
```

I don't know where to execute the out_pm update with this method.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_TimeLog(
   log_id      INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,emp_name    VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL
  ,date_log    VARCHAR(23) NOT NULL
  ,in_am       VARCHAR(8) NULL
  ,out_am      VARCHAR(4) NULL
  ,total_am    VARCHAR(4) NULL
  ,in_pm       VARCHAR(4) NULL
  ,out_pm      VARCHAR(8) NULL
  ,total_pm    VARCHAR(4) NULL
  ,grand_total VARCHAR(4) NULL
  ,id          INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO tbl_TimeLog(log_id,emp_name,date_log,in_am,out_am,total_am,in_pm,out_pm,total_pm,grand_total,id) VALUES (36,'Jhefrey','2016-09-06 00:00:00.000','12:07:40',NULL,NULL,NULL,'12:08:24',NULL,NULL,10);
```

Comment: Why do you have columns for AM and PM? And why do you need both AM and PM? You really should be using the datetime datatype and not try using some string with a format. And drop the whole idea of InAM and InPM. If you are deadset on sticking with not using  the proper datatype why do you need both AM and PM? If it isn't AM it must be PM right?

Comment: it is for time log of  employee's

Comment: I understand that part, but why do you have columns for AM and PM? If you are storing your data as datetime you don't need other columns. 09:00 is 9am and 21:00 is 9pm.

Comment: actually there our four columns.
first is Time_IN for AM
second is Time_OUT for AM
third is Time_IN for PM
fourth is Time_OUT for PM

and the reason why I compare the Date string with AM is to execute the  stored procedures based on what they belong AM or PM

Comment: Oh I think I see what you are saying. You have 4 possible time punches per day. I know this is for school but you should consider things like second or third shifts when naming you columns. A person on third shift would use your AM time in column in the afternoon and your PM columns in the morning. This would be infinitely clearer if you posted details about your tables. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Hello I've updated my question with the table details.

Comment: You really need to store time information with the time datatype instead of using varchar data. The biggest issue though is I have no idea what you are struggling with here.

Comment: @Sean Lange I am strugling with how will I achieve this. Like if there is no entry on employee id with date today then data will be inserted with in_am data inside of it. and there will be no insert for the same id and date but it will be update to out_am,in_pm,out_pm

Comment: I am sure this makes sense to you because you close to this project. Unfortunately this last description of the problem is not making it clear to me what the issue is. To be honest, that table structure is causing you some pain because it isn't normalized properly and the datatypes are simply not correct for what you are storing.

Comment: Well thanks for taking your time answer to my question but I'm glad I found a solution for that

Comment: Glad you found a solution....too bad you didn't explain the problem so we could help.

Comment: yeah sorry for that